# How can I create custom store url in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Let my website url is like `example.com` and there are 3 stores and i want to access my store like this `example.com/ch` for china and example.com/ru for
`Russia` so how can i achieved this in magento.

Answer (score 3):

This option is already available in Magento. You can add store codes in url by

turn on `System > Config > Web > Add Store Code to URLs` to **Yes** from backend.